# New to TypeScript, what does this chunk of code do?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

```
interface CountryMap {
  ISO_A3?: string
  NAME?: string
  color?: string
}

export const GlobalStats = ({
  tooltipContent,
}: {
  tooltipContent: CountryMap
}) => {...}

<GlobalStats tooltipContent={tooltipContent} />
```

Hi guys, I'm trying to make sense of an open source code and need help with this specific line:

> ***({tooltipContent,}: {tooltipContent: CountryMap})***

It looks like it's taking a javascript object and to "cast" into an interface but the syntax looks very different from what I've googled.

1. Why is there also a comma after the tooltipContent in the first curly braces?
2. Is this a shorthand?
3. Can someone please destructure/eil5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing two things: it takes as an argument an object with a `tooltipContent` property, whose value is of the type `CountryMap`. That's what the colon does:

```
: { tooltipContent: CountryMap }
```

(just like, in any argument list, you'd see something like `argName: string` to indicate that the argument is a string)

It might be clearer to understand the syntax if you made it a named type in advance:

```
type Arg = {
  tooltipContent: CountryMap;
};

export const GlobalStats = ({
  tooltipContent,
}: Arg) => {...}
```

In addition, it's [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `tooltipContent` property of the argument and putting it into a standalone variable name for use in the function body.

In ordinary Javascript, without the types, the function would look like:

```
export const GlobalStats = ({ tooltipContent }) => {
  // reference tooltipContent here
};
```

which is equivalent to

```
export const GlobalStats = (obj) => {
  const tooltipContent = obj.tooltipContent;
  // reference tooltipContent here
};
```

which is also equivalent to

```
export const GlobalStats = (obj) => {
  const { tooltipContent } = obj;
  // reference tooltipContent here
};
```

(destructuring the *argument itself* like in your original Typescript code is the most concise, though, so it's often preferred)

Comment: Thanks CP, you've sent me on the right path. Anyways, a friend pointed out that the trailing comma was added by eslint/prettier which I've since confirmed.